# I have this problem that I need to Reverse the first word and the third word using a stack/s and swap the positions of the reversed words

Tags: java, stack

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter a string: ");

        String str = in.nextLine();

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            stack.push(str.charAt(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse:");

        while(!stack.empty()){
            System.out.print(stack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done is reverse the whole sentence,
for example "Input string: This is the new normal" and my output is "lamron wen eht si sihT".

What the expected output is:
"Output : eht is sihT new normal."

Comment: looks like only half of string needs to be reversed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reverse the **first** word and the **third** word using a stack/s and **swap the positions of the reversed words**.

You need to handle 3 things:

1. Identify 1st word from the input line/string and reverse it
2. Identify 3rd word from the input line/string and reverse it
3. Swap 1st and 3rd word which are reversed

In your logic, you are using stack to **reverse entire input string without looking for 1st or 3rd word**. That's the reason you are getting whole input in the reversed format as output.

You need to split input string by space to get array of words, reverse only 1st and 3rd word from that array and swap those 2 words only. At he end, join all words (array of words) with space to generate the desired output. Below is one of the ways to solve it (here is [working sample](https://ideone.com/JrjkK9) with your example):

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter a string: ");
        
        // split input string in to words by space
        String[] words = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        
        // performing reverse operation if 3 words are in the input at minimum
        // else output is same as input
        if (words.length >= 3) {
            String rev1 = reverse(words[0]); // reverse word-1
            String rev3 = reverse(words[2]); // reverse word-3
            // swap word 1 and 3
            words[0] = rev3;
            words[2] = rev1;
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse: " + String.join(" ", words));
    }
    
    public static String reverse(String word) {
        if (word == null) {
            return word;
        }
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            stack.push(word.charAt(i));
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(!stack.empty()){
            sb.append(stack.pop());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh yes, thank you for your help, I'm new at coding, That's why I got confused.